# WSO2 Error: Unable to retrieve custom url info from APIM Admin API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 3.2.0/docker-compose

And i have this setup for APIM (as reverse proxy using Nginx)

https://apim.mydomain.com/devportal

https://apim.mydomain.com/publisher

also i have this reverse proxy for the analytics dashboard:

https://apim-analytics.mydomain.com

however, when i open the dashboard i see this error in the web console and dark screen:

```
{"error":"Internal_Server_Error","description":"Error in login to the uri \u0027analytics-dashboard\u0027. Error: Unable to retrieve custom url info from APIM Admin API"}
```

i suspect the issue is here `apim-analytics-dashboard/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml` (wrong configuration):

```
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:own apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:edit apim_analytics:monitoring_dashboard:view apim_analytics:business_analytics:own apim_analytics:business_analytics:edit apim_analytics:business_analytics:view apim_analytics:api_analytics:own apim_analytics:api_analytics:edit apim_analytics:api_analytics:view apim_analytics:application_analytics:own apim_analytics:application_analytics:edit apim_analytics:application_analytics:view
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://api-manager:9443/client-registration/v0.17/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://api-manager:9443/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://api-manager:9443/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://apim-analytics.mydomain.com
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://apim.mydomain.com/publisher
    devPortalUrl: https://apim.mydomain.com/devportal
    externalLogoutUrl: https://api-manager:9443/oidc/logout
    adminServiceBaseUrl: https://api-manager:9443
```

Comment: There is an issue with your `adminServiceBaseUrl`. Could you please verify whether that endpoint is working properly?

Comment: Hi @Sarangan , i have changed `adminServiceBaseUrl` to `https://apim.mydomain.com` which is a reverse proxy for localhost:9443, still the same issue.

Comment: Did you configure the reverse proxy as mentioned here, https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#step-3-configure-the-reverse-proxy-settings-in-the-product

Comment: I got exacty the same error... then changed publisherUrl   to https://apim.mydomain.com/  which no subcontext and devPortalUrl to https://apim.mydomain.com/ also. Now it works!